# How to return words ending with 'ing' using rfind?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am looking to return all the words ending in 'ing' using rfind.

```
x = str(input("Enter some random words: "))

for y in x.split():
    if x.rfind(r'\b(\w+ing)\b'):
        print(y, end=' ')
```

When I enter 'How are you doing and hows it going' as the input, I am getting the whole string as the output. I want to get the word 'doing' and 'going' as the output.

Comment: Where did you see that [`rfind`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind) takes a regex? Why do you test `x` in the loop if `y` is the variable that actually changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly use `str.endswith` on each word:

```py
for y in x.split():
    if y.endswith('ing'):
        print(y, end=' ')
```

If you want to use regular expressions, import the `re` module and use `re.findall`:

```py
import re
print(*re.findall(r'\w+ing\b', x))
```